# Disable sharing of playlists in Spotify App

Tags: privacy, spotify

On Spotify for Windows, there is a setting "Automatically make new playlists public", which I disabled, since I don't want to do that.

In the settings on the Spotify Android App however, this option is missing. Or at least I am not finding it.

Does anyone know a better way to keep my playlists private than manually clicking "Unpublish" for every new playlist I add?

Answer (score 2):

Just go to settings and enable "Private Sessions" That will disable sharing of the songs you listen to.

[Steps to enable Private sessions-](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20128261-285/how-to-enable-private-listening-on-spotify-for-android/)

> Step 1: Go to the Android Market and update your Spotify app.
>
> Step 2: Launch the Spotify for Android app, then in the lower
>   right-hand corner, tap on "More," then "Settings." 
>           [image: Pic1]
>   Step 3: Check the box next to "Private Session."
>
> Step 4: When you go back to your playlists, you'll see the "Private
>   Session" indicator at the top. 
>                      [image: Pic2]
>
> That's it. Now you can listen to Spotify without advertising your
>   playlists to your Facebook friends. Keep in mind that after 6 hours of
>   idle time, Private Session will automatically disable itself.

Comment: While I appreciate the nice screenshots in your answer, this is unfortunately not what I was looking for. I was already aware of these "private sessions", I'm looking for something that doesn't make my privacy expire after 6 hours...

Comment: Sorry but I don't think it can be done :(

Comment: Just use a Windows Spotify one time. Setting is also valid for the app. My playlists are hidden by default.